# Construct a homeomorphic map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know the fact that if $x$ is a point in $\Bbb R^n$, then $\Bbb R^n\setminus \{x\} $ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}\times \Bbb R$, how to constrcut the homeomorphic map?

Comment: $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{x\}$ is a manifold of dimension $n$, whereas $S^n \times \mathbb R$ is a manifold of dimension $n+1$. Manifolds of different dimension are *never* homeomorphic.

Comment: sorry,it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define continuous function $f:\Bbb R^n\backslash\{x\}\to\Bbb S^{n-1}\times \Bbb R$ by $$f(y)=\bigg(\frac{y-x}{||y-x||},\log_e(||y-x||)\bigg),\forall y\in \Bbb R^n\backslash\{x\}.$$

with continuous inverse $g:\Bbb S^{n-1}\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n\backslash\{x\}$ by $$g(v,r)=e^rv+x,\forall v\in \Bbb S^{n-1},\forall r\in \Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Think about radial projection from punctured Euclidean space to the sphere. The fibers of the projection are radial rays. Each of these rays is homeomorphic to the real line. Each ray corresponds to a unique point on the sphere, and vice-versa.

Also, don't you mean $S^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

$re^{i\theta}\to(e^{i\theta},r)$, for $r\gt0$.  (Then recall $\Bbb R^+\cong \Bbb R$.)